# Where Can I Find The Bootanimation.zip For A ROM On GitHub

Tags: boot-animation

I'm looking for a bootanimation.zip from the latest Dirty Unicorns ROM.
However, I don't want to download the ROM, TWRP backup, wipe, install, extract bootanimation.zip, wipe, TWRP restore just to get it.

I was hoping to download it directly from GitHub. However, the ROM source code is split into loads of repos and I don't know where to look.

Where in the source tree and in which repo is the bootanimation.zip typically stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootanimation.zip will not be present in the Android Source Code or the kernel source code..

It's gets included from the vendor blobs while building the system.img ..

So, you'll have to check the corresponding ROM's vendor repository..

For CyanogenMod, it's here: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_vendor_cyanogen/tree/master/prebuilt

For Dirty Unicorns, it's here: https://github.com/DirtyUnicorns/android_vendor_du/tree/m/prebuilt/common/media

For Paranoid Android, it's here: https://github.com/AOSPA/android_vendor_pa/tree/nougat/prebuilt/bootanimation

For Pac ROM: https://github.com/PAC-ROM/android_vendor_pac/tree/pac-6.0/prebuilt/common/media

(These links are subject to change, please edit if there's any change or to add any other ROM's link)